# Apparently Invalid travis.yml fails after adding deployment configuration

Tags: azure, yaml, travis-ci

My Current travis.yml file looks like so:

```
language: csharp
solution: SealingServer.sln
install:
  - nuget restore SealingServer.sln
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5" SealingServer.sln
 deploy:
  provider: azure_web_apps
  username: azure_deployment_user       # If AZURE_WA_USERNAME isn't set
  password: azure_deployment_password   # If AZURE_WA_PASSWORD isn't set
  site: azure_deployment_sitename       # If AZURE_WA_SITE isn't set
  verbose: true
  on:
   branch: master
```

It was working previously when it looked like this:

```
language: csharp
solution: SealingServer.sln
install:
  - nuget restore SealingServer.sln
script:
  - xbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFrameworkVersion="v4.5" SealingServer.sln
```

I'm not sure what additions caused it to start failing silently. When I run it through the official linter https://lint.travis-ci.org/ I get this error:

> syntax error: (): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 1 column 5

What did I do wrong with my travis.yml to cause this breakage? And what should I be doing differently to deploy to Azure using travis.